# How to group people so everyone meets?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I have sort of a stupid maths problem which I was thinking about recently, given the UK's covid rules about only being able to meet with 6 people max.

If I have a group of $N$ friends (e.g. 15) and everyone wants to hang out with everyone else, what's the fewest number of meet-ups we would need to accomplish this (with max 6 people in each)?

This seems similar to the social golfer problem. Is it possible to come up with a general solution?

(obviously not planning to go and do this in person, but I was thinking about this and couldn't come up with a solution)

Comment: if you have $4$ friends and every group has a max of $3$ persons, can you figure out the method?

Comment: Well if my friends are [a,b,c,d] 

Then one solution would be:
abc
bcd
da-

But I'm not sure what the method for working this out would be for different sizes. 4c3 gives you the total number of combinations of people, but many of those combinations are not needed?

Comment: It seems to me that the answer is ${15 \choose 6} = 5005 $, but this is just a guess.

Comment: When you say that everyone wants to hang out with everyone else, do you mean that each person wants to meet each other person at least once, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Denote $M+1$ the max number of friends per group, $N+1$ the number of people, and $S_{k}$ the minimum number of meetings required for $k$ people. There are ${N+1\choose 2}$ pairs of people which need to meet. We eliminate at most $M+1 \choose 2$ of these pairs per meeting. Hence $S_{N+1} \geq \lceil {N+1\choose 2}{M+1 \choose 2}^{-1} \rceil$.

Applying the identity

\begin{equation}
n = \lceil \frac{n}{m} \rceil + \cdots + \lceil \frac{n-m+1}{m} \rceil
\end{equation}

for all integers $n$ and positive integers $m$, counting with induction gives

\begin{align}
S_{N+1} &\leq S_{N} + \lceil \frac{N}{M}\rceil \\ 
&\leq \cdots \leq \lceil\frac{N}{M} \rceil + \lceil\frac{N-1}{M} \rceil + \cdots + \lceil \frac{M}{M} \rceil \\
&=\left(\lceil\frac{N}{M}\rceil + \cdots + \lceil \frac{N-M+1}{M} \rceil\right) +\left(\lceil\frac{N-M}{M}\rceil+\cdots+\lceil\frac{N-2M+1}{M}\rceil \right) + \cdots \\
&\leq N + (N-M) + (N-2M) + \cdots + (N-\left(\lfloor N/M \rfloor -1\right)M) \\
&=N\lfloor \frac{N}{M} \rfloor- M\lfloor \frac{N}{M} \rfloor \left(\lfloor \frac{N}{M} \rfloor - 1 \right)2^{-1} \\
&=\lfloor \frac{N}{M} \rfloor\left(N - \frac{M}{2} \left(\lfloor\frac{N}{M}\rfloor -1 \right) \right) \\
&\leq \frac{N}{M}\left(\frac{N}{2} + M\right) \\
&=\frac{N(N+2M)}{2M}
\end{align}

where the first $\leq$ followed by induction, the second by appending the missing terms to the final grouped summation. Lastly
\begin{equation}
\lceil \frac{N(N+1)}{M(M+1)} \rceil \leq S_{N+1} \leq \lfloor \frac{N(N+2M)}{2M} \rfloor
\end{equation}

The upper bound is rather large. It can be improved somewhat by assuming person $k+1$ has already met people from an earlier person's turn and doing the same computation.

$\textbf{Edit}$: A strategy like this is person $k+1$'s first meeting always includes $k$ and preferrably people $k$ has not met with numbers less than $k-1$. Then $k$ has always already met at least $M-1$ of the remaining people on their turn.

Similarly by induction

\begin{equation}
S_{N+1} \leq \lceil \frac{N}{M} \rceil + \lceil \frac{N-M}{M} \rceil + \lceil \frac{N-M-1}{M} \rceil + \cdots + \lceil \frac{1}{M} \rceil \\  
\end{equation}

which is the previous calculation with $N$ replaced by $N-M$ plus $\lceil \frac{N}{M} \rceil + M-1$. So

\begin{equation}
S_{N+1} \leq \lfloor \frac{(N-M)(N+M)}{2M} + \frac{N}{M} + M \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{(N+1)^2+M^2-1}{2M} \rfloor
\end{equation}

$N = 14, M = 5$ gives $7 \leq S_{15} \leq 24$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** We can restate the problem as follows:

- We consider a *[complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph)* graph with $N$ vertices. The vertices of the graph represent the friends and since each two of them know each other we draw an edge between each two vertices, giving a complete graph.
- A group of $6$ friends can be represented as complete subgraph of size $6$. Such a group is called *clique* and we are asking for the minimum number of $6$-size *[cliques which cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover)* a complete graph of size $N$.

An answer to this question is given at *[math overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/254012/cover-a-complete-graph-by-smaller-complete-graphs)*. The paper *[Approximation algorithms for the k-clique covering problem](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2349569_Approximation_Algorithms_for_the_k-Clique_Covering_Problem)* might also be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

All members of a group are considered to have met each other.

In general, if we have $N$ people and the maximum group size is $k$, we can represent $N$ as

$N = \left\lfloor {k \over 2} \right\rfloor n + c$, where
$$c = N \mod \left\lfloor {k \over 2} \right\rfloor$$

This splits the $N$ people into $n+ (k \mod 2)$ subgroups of maximum size size $\left\lfloor {k \over 2} \right\rfloor$ each.

We can choose two subgroups and group them together into a group of size $2\left\lfloor {k \over 2} \right\rfloor \le k$.

The number of such combinations of subgroups is

$$C(n, 2)$$

For the case of $N = 15, k = 6$, we have

$$N = 15 = \left\lfloor 6 \over 2 \right\rfloor \times 5 = 3 \times 5 + 0$$

So, we have $n = 5, c = 0$ and the number of minimum meetups = $C(5, 2)$