# combinatorics: what is the smallest number of fixed-size sets that together contain all possible pairs?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the following problem: let $S$ be a subset of size $d$ of the set of the numbers from 1 to $n$. We say the $S$ contains the pair $(k,m)$ if it is a subset of $S$. for example, $(1,4,6)$ contains the pairs $(1,4),(1,6),(4,6)$.

Now, we would like to generate a number of such sets (all with size $d$) that will together  contain **all** $n(n-1)/2$ possible pairs.

for example, for $d=3$ and $n=6$, the following 7 sets:

$(1,2,3) \\
(4,5,6) \\
(1,4,5) \\
(1,6,2) \\
(2,4,5) \\
(3,4,5) \\
(3,6,5)$

together contain all of the 15 possible pairs of numbers from 1 to 6, however it has many redundancies: for example the pair $(4,5)$ appears in 4 different ones.

for general $d$ and $n$, what is the **smallest** number of sets that together contains all possible pairs, and how to algorithmically generate it ?

A trivial upper bound is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2\lfloor d/2 \rfloor}$, since we can clearly accommodate at least $\lfloor d/2 \rfloor$ distinct pairs in any set, however as demonstrated by the above example we can do much better than that.

Comment: any guess? Or bounds you found? Where does this problem come from?

Comment: @Exodd I added one trivial bound I could think of to the question. This comes from a optimization problem where I'm trying to cover as many parameter configurations as possible, and I know that  the target function only depends on the existence of a specific pair in the configuration

Comment: Lower bound: $\left\lceil \frac{n-1}{d-1} \right\rceil \times \frac{n}{d}$

Comment: If we treat $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ as a complete graph of $n$ vertices, and the subsets $S$ as cliques of size $d$ in the complete graph, then this becomes somewhat related to the **edge clique cover problem**. There is a relevant question in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/254012/cover-a-complete-graph-by-smaller-complete-graphs, though I'm not sure if that will answer your question.

Comment: @DanielMathias Thanks can you explain how you arrived at this bound ?

Comment: How many times does each element need to appear?

Comment: It seems that you want sets but write tuples, e.g., $(1,2,3)$ should be $\{1,2,3\}$. Also in the size 2 objects it seems you consider $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ to be the same. They also should be written as subsets binomial coefficients count subsets.

Comment: @DanielMathias I see each element needs to appear in at least $\lceil \frac{n-1}{d-1}\rceil$ sets, but then the lower bound should be  $\lceil \frac{n-1}{d-1}\rceil \times \lceil \frac{n}{d}\rceil$ no ?

Comment: Let $x=\left\lceil \frac{n-1}{d-1} \right\rceil$, then the lower bound is $\frac{xn}{d}$ (or $\left\lceil \frac{xn}{d} \right\rceil$ if you like)

Comment: Just an hint: you can model an Integer Linear Program in binary variables in a way somewhat similar to [this](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/9334/9517) (see also the linked questions there).

Comment: Better hint: for the minimum number see this [equivalent formulation of the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3837974/573047) and the links in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimal case (i.e., each pair appearing exactly once) of you are looking for is called a [Block design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design).

As suggested in the comments, for small parameters, the requirements can be converted into an Integer Linear Program.

Specifically:

> Given a finite set $X$ (of elements called points) and integers
> $k, r, λ ≥ 1,$ we define a $2-$design (or BIBD, standing for balanced incomplete block design) B to be a family of $k-$element subsets of $X$, called blocks, such that any $x$ in $X$ is contained in $r$ blocks, and any pair of distinct points $x$ and $y$ in $X$ is contained in $λ$ blocks. Here, the condition that any $x$ in $X$ is contained in $r$ blocks is redundant, as shown below.

So you want $\lambda=1,$ (each pair must appear exactly once) if possible. It won't be possible for all parameters due to the equations
$$bk=vr,\quad \lambda(v-1)=(v-1)=r(k-1)
$$
needing to be satisfied for an optimal solution to exist. Here $b$ is the number of blocks, $v=n$ in your terminology, and $k=d$ in your terminology. So
$$
bd=nr, \quad (n-1)=r(d-1)
$$
must hold. Due to these constraints only certain parameters will give optimal solutions.

More generally you want a *Covering Design* where you want each $2-$tuple to appear at least once.

Both these problems are difficult to solve in general. There is a website of covering designs [here](https://www.dmgordon.org/cover/) maintained by Dan Gordon.

Comment: Thanks for the references. Dan Gordon's website provides covering designs up to $v=100$ which is quite useful for my problem. Are you aware of available tools to search for covering designs with  $v \ge 100$ ?